# php foreach() & glob() INSERT INTO w/ exec() is only INSERTING last .csv (of 30) into table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, exec, glob

The last .csv file is processed and loaded into myTable, but there are 30 other .csv files prior to that - the **.csv files are all being read** because I echoed them out to the CLI and they are printed to the screen, but I cannot resolve why **ONLY the last .csv is being INSERTED into myTable**? **Any ideas?**

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
 $dir = "H:/path/20130116/";
 $files = "*.csv";
     foreach(glob($dir.$files) as $file)  { 
          exec("mysql -u root -e \"USE mydb; myTable; LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $file . "' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'\"; ");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a `commit`.  Just a guess.

Comment: Upon more and more testing, removing the first call to myTable; in the MySQL line seems to have resolved the problem. I am going to run more tests and will confirm with an answered own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon more and more testing, removing the first call to myTable; in the MySQL line seems to have resolved the problem.